# How to set eclipse for android development?

Tags: java, android, eclipse, mobile-development

I just downloaded java JDK 8 and set the environment variables for JDK and JRE, downloaded android SDK extracted them directly to C: (there were no platform tools so I used the command line to download them) and also set the environment variables. And I downloaded eclipse oxygen and I installed new software for ADT Plugin. When I set preferences I referred to the SDK folder and hit apply but nothing seems to happen like no SDK targets are listed. Hhuhuhuhuhuhuhu T^T I have deleted everything from Java, SDK, eclipse and downloaded them all again while disabling my antivirus but that didn't fix it. I also cant open my Android SDK Manager using eclipse, like it shows that it's loading but after that nothing happens even if I wait for 10 mins nothing shows up on screen, not even the command line that seems to just flash briefly which is what most people are having problems with when I search google. Can someone please tell me what to do?? I'm mainly using eclipse for android projects in school

Comment: Save yourself some trouble and use Android Studio instead https://developer.android.com/studio/index.html

Comment: i'd like too but i dont think my laptop can take it. also, why did you edit my post? i'm sorry i'm not trying to be mean, i'm new here XD. Should the terms be written properly?

Answer (score 2):

By the end of 2015, Google ended the development and official support for the Android Developer Tools (ADT) in Eclipse.

As stated by Google, every app development project should be migrated to Android Studio.

So you should migrate your eclipse project to android studio.

Comment: really?? O.O in school we use eclipse(helios -.-) because the computers cant handle android studio. my professor said that it requires an i7 and about 8GB RAM for android to function well. my laptop is only i5 and has 4GB RAM installed so i opted for eclipse. I have friends who use eclipse oxygen and could do their android projects just fine though :'( . Others downloaded android studio but they said it lags sometimes because their equipment couldnt meet the requirements